# gdb, connect to a running process started with gdbserver

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb, ncurses

I want to write a small text-editor just for the fun of it in C and ncurses.

So I compiled it using the -g option and got a file called "editor".
I can do `cgdb editor input-for-text-editor.txt` and can debug it no problems except that ncurses
uses the stdout... you know it breaks the in/out that gdb uses.

So what I decided to do, is to use gdbserver to start my program and connect to that process for another gdb session.

So I did the following:

```
gdbserver port:1234 editor input-for-text-editor.txt
```

And in another terminal:

```
gdb editor
target remote localhost:1234
```

At this point, I'm connected to the process:

```
bt
#1  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffffffea7b in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fffffffea82 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

But as you can see, I don't have the information regarding what line is being executed.
Furthermore, if I put a break in main +30 (that's where the infinite loop is) and press `c`, it doesnt break there. Instead it just continues to execute forever.

Can someone tell me please, what am I doing wrong? How can I connect to my process from another gdb in order to decouple the stdout/in of the process with that of the debugger?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: have u compiles using -g flag?

Comment: yes, definetky I have.

Comment: I though I did, but you are right, i didnt. wow. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any one watching this thread the problem was solved by compiling with `-g` flag

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options

Comment: I'm assuming the problem was *not* compiling with the `-g` flag.